# Best tool for text representation to deep learning

Tags: keras, deep-learning, word2vec, lsa, glove

so I wanna ask you which is the best tool used to prepare my text to deep learning?

What is the difference between `Word2Vec`, `Glove`, `Keras`, `LSA`...

Comment: Please avoid open-ended questions or high-level comparisons between methods or frameworks. https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: For a general introduction to deep learning for text with Keras, I can personally recommend the relevant chapters in 'Deep learning with Python' by François Chollet.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a pre-trained embedding to represent the sentence into a vector or a matrix. There are a lot of sources where you can find pre-trained embeddings that use different dataset (for instance all the Wikipedia) to train their models. These models can have different length, but normally each word is represented with 100 or 300 dimensions.

[Pre-trained embeddings](http://vectors.nlpl.eu/repository/)
[Pre-trained embeddings 2](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/blob/master/pretrained-vectors.md)